# pip install keep asking user and password

Tags: python, pip, nexus

I am new to PyPI hosting on private, so I hosted private PyPI repo on Nexus3 with python 2.7, I put the following in pip.conf:

```
[global]
extra-index-url = https://username:password@example.com/repository/package/simple
```

However, it keeps pops up to ask the user and password. Since I pass the username and password already in URL, should it just pass without aksing? Anyone have the same case and how do you solve it?

Comment: Do you have a symbol in your password? Looks like there have been reports of it not working if there is: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/51 and scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks @wholevinski, I do have a special character in the password. Do you know any work around for this?

Comment: Based on the comments, I don't think so. It looks like if you don't URL encode it, it doesn't get sent right. Then if you _do_ URL encode it, pip doesn't decode it...so, not looking good. Do you have access to change the password? At the very least to verify that this is the problem.

Comment: Cool, thanks @wholevinski, I am requesting it and give it a shot, this seems very likely the case. please add it as answer :)

Comment: Answer posted; also, does the same username and password work if you enter it in the interactive prompt that comes up? If so, then I'm convinced that's it.

Comment: It works for interactive prompt, thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments in this issue thread, it seems like pip might not be able to handle special characters in the password right:

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/51

This comment in particular seems to confirm the issue:

> vladignatyev I just ran into the same problem you mentioned, of it
>   asking for user/password interactively. I narrowed down the problem to
>   having a symbol in the password that needs url-encoding. If I don't
>   url-encode the password, the URL can't be parsed. If I do url-encode
>   the password, I think pip isn't url-decoding it before attempting to
>   authenticate.

It looks like the only workaround right now is to use a password without characters that need URL encoding.

Comment: After removing special character, it works perfectly!

Comment: Awesome, hopefully they fix that soon!

Answer (score 3):

Note: I don't have enough rep to comment to reply to wholevinski

This bug got fixed in this [pull request](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4393) back in April, it's just not slated to be released until [milestone 10.0](https://github.com/pypa/pip/milestone/23), <strike>which hasn't been released yet</strike>.

**Update:** [pip 10.0](https://github.com/pypa/pip/releases/tag/10.0.0) is out now.